# Read specific tag in a RSS feed

Tags: c#, rss, rss-reader

I have the following RSS feed. I want to read the information inside a specific description tag. For example i want to get the information in the description tag when its title tag consists of the current day.I cant figure out how to do this. Please help

```
<item>
<title>Forecast for Saturday as of Jul. 14 5:30 AM IST</title> //If today is Saturday get information in description tag
<link>http://www.wunderground.com/global/stations/43466.html</link>    
  <description>
Thunderstorm. Low:26 &amp;deg; C.
  </description>
  <pubDate>Sat, 14 Jul 2012 00:00:00 GMT</pubDate>
  <guid isPermaLink="false">1342267200-1-night</guid>
</item>
<item>
<title>Forecast for Sunday as of Jul. 14 5:30 AM IST</title>
<link>http://www.wunderground.com/global/stations/43466.html</link>
  <description>
Chance of a Thunderstorm. High:30 &amp;deg; C.
  </description>
  <pubDate>Sat, 14 Jul 2012 00:00:00 GMT</pubDate>
  <guid isPermaLink="false">1342353600-2-day</guid>
 </item>
```

I was able to get the current day using:

```
string datenow = DateTime.Today.ToString("dddd / M / yyyy");
string[] words= datenow.Split(' ');
string day = words[0];
```

This is how i am reading the RSS feed:

```
 public class RssReader
    {
        public static List<RssNews> Read(string url)
        {
            var webClient = new WebClient();

            string result = webClient.DownloadString(url);

            XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(result);

            return (from descendant in document.Descendants("item")
                    select new RssNews()
                    {
                        Description = descendant.Element("description").Value,
                        Title = descendant.Element("title").Value,
                        PublicationDate = descendant.Element("pubDate").Value
                    }).ToList();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your Requirement you just want to get description of current day .You have list of News feeds with Title ,description ..etc Now You can change your class (add a method in Your class )  if day is Current Day

public static string GetCurrentDayDescription(){

```
   var lst = Read("url");
   var resDescription = (from x in lst where x.Title.Contains(day) 
                          select x.Description).ToArray() ;
    return resDescription[0] ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use XmlSerializer to deserialize the rss feed directly without manual mapping.. You will need to modify your `RssNews` object to map correctly, e.g.:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName="item")]
public class RssNews
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "pubDate")]
    public string PublicationDate  { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "link")]
    public string Link { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "guid")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Now you should be able to use deserializer:

```
    var feed = new List<RssNews>();
    using (var webClient = new WebClient())
    {

        string result = webClient.DownloadString(url);
        using (var stringReader = new StringReader(result))
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(feed.GetType());
            feed = (List<RssNews>)serializer.Deserialize(stringReader);
        }
    }
    return feed;
```